# finding the smallest value that is divisible by 7

Tags: c

I would like to find the smallest number that is divisible by 7. There is no error generated but there is no output value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main(){
    int N[5], K, i;
    int smallestVal;

    for (i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]);
    }
    
    smallestVal = N[0];
    
    for (i=0; i<=6 ; i++)
    {
        if (N[i] < smallestVal) && (N[i]%7==0)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that an array of `5` elements only have indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive)?

Comment: There is buffer overflow on your code, i must not be greater than 4 since it is the index of N.

Comment: i hv changed the index to 6 and for loop to (i=0; i<=5; i++). i got an error: 32:30: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token. i cant figure out why

Comment: The value of smallestVal should be changed instead of printing 1.  The print of smallestval should be after the loop

Comment: @cup u mean at the loop for (i=0; i<=6 ; i++)
    {
        if (N[i] < smallestVal) && (N[i]%7==0)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
    }?

Comment: Yes. On the second loop.  Is your error in the first or second loop

Comment: on the second loop but i still get the same error: "expected identifier before ‘(’ token"

Comment: The loop condition `i <= 5` will *include* the index `5`, which is still out of bounds of your array.

Comment: You can't use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to determine if the input succeeded or failed. Failing to do so invites *Undefined Behavior* in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of your array does not match your `for` loop.
The loop will run 7 times, while there are only 5 slots available.
You want:

```c
for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
```

Your `if` condition is missing a set of brackets around the conditions:

```c
if (N[i] < smallestVal) && (N[i]%7==0)
```

It is hard to say why you aren't printing anything right now without knowing your inputs, but it possibly has to do with how you're setting the smallest value.

For starters, this code with print all numbers that are divisible by 7:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main(){
    int N[5], i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]);
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (N[i]%7==0)
        {
            printf("%d", N[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, you'll want to track the lowest number that's divisible using a variable.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main(){
    int N[5], i;
    int smallestVal;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]);
    }
    
    smallestVal = -1;
    
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if ((N[i] < smallestVal || smallestVal == -1) && (N[i]%7==0))
        {
            smallestVal = N[i];
        }
    }
    
    if (smallestVal != -1)
    {
        printf("%d", smallestVal);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("No number divisible by 7");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I've set `smallestVal` to `-1` at the start.
If a number is found while it is still `-1`, this is overwritten.
If it is still `-1`, you know that none of them were divisible.

Comment: the output shows 11 instead of 1. the sample input is 5, 14 , 7, 8, 2,  4 the output will be 1 as 7 is the smallest to be divided by 7.

Comment: Your sample input includes characters that are not accounted for in the scanf call. You also have more inputs than expected. You'll have to expand the buffer size and change the scanf call to consume the commas.

Comment: Im new to c programming and i dont get what u mean, can u give me an example?

Comment: @Chewjunnie if you want to print `1` instead of the actual value, just use `printf("1")` instead of `printf("%d", smallestVal);`.

Comment: ok, i dont really understand this part "if (smallestVal != -1)". i tot for the for loop infront, the purpose is to find the smallest number? does it mean that when it loops, the smallest number is still -1?

Comment: @Chewjunnie Use Omid's comment to print 1, but you'll also want to change the scanf line to something like `scanf("%d%*[,\n]")` to consume the comma or newline.

Comment: The `smallestVal != -1` part is assuming you wanted to print the smallest number. -1 would be if it didn't find a number divisible by 7. The `(N[i] < smallestVal || smallestVal == -1)` part would overwrite -1 if it found one. If you only want to print 1 if it finds a number, you can remove this.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to correct your array or loop size. Besides you're comparing the first element of your array as the `smallestVal`, instead use a large value like `INT_MAX` (in limits.h header) as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main() {
    int N[5], K, i;
    int smallestVal;

    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &N[i]);
    }
    smallestVal = INT_MAX;
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((N[i] < smallestVal) && (N[i] % 7 == 0)) {
            smallestVal = N[i];
        }
    }
    if (smallestVal != INT_MAX)
        printf("1");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the output shows 11 instead of 1. the sample input is 5, 14 , 7, 8, 2, 4 the output will be 1 as 7 is the smallest to be divided by 7.

Comment: @Chewjunnie check again. I didn't update `smallestVal` in my original answer.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

void smallest_number();
int main(){
    int a[N];
    int i;
    printf("enter the array elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    smallest_number(a);
}
void smallest_number(int *a){
    int i,smallest_value;
    printf("smallest element\n");
    smallest_value=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        if(smallest_value<a[i]){
            continue;
        }
        else if(smallest_value>=a[i]){
            smallest_value=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d",smallest_value);
}
```

i defined an macro for the size of the array and i took a variable to compare a value of the first element of the array after that its just conditions to pick out the smallest value.
i hope it'll workout for  your doubt